# Why I run python script from golang wrong

Tags: go, exec

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "bytes"
)

func main() {
    cmd :="/root/hi.py > /root/1.log"

    out,err:= exec.Command("python","-c",cmd).Output()
    fmt.Printf("Out: %s ", string(out))
    fmt.Printf("Err: %s ", err.Error())

}
```

Error: **no such file error: /root/hi.py > /root/1.log**

```
//hi.py 

#! /usr/bin/python

print('hello world')
```

Comment: Clearly indicate the file name with path and its content, the command you put and the output of you command, so that people can identify the issue more easily.

Comment: Two major bugs: You are executing a shell script (redirections with `>` are executed by the shell). Each argument must be it's own string.

Answer (score 1):

Where’s file `hi.py` located? Try to split it by arguments, it seems to try filename `/root/hi.py > /root/1.log`